# PHP4 to PHP5 Upgrade - set class properties

Tags: php

I need to get our server running on php5 but we have an old CMS that has issues I need to bandaid till we have the time to have a new CMS setup and the old data (about 4000 pages with great SEO) moved.

The guts of the old CMS would load/save the page data as class variables/properties that were then serialised and saved to a file, and unserialised to be used, all by methods in the class.

```
$this = $ToolBox->fileUnSerialize($myFile);
```

You can't do that in php5 as you can not reassign the $this variable.

I could do this:

```
$vardata = $ToolBox->fileUnSerialize($myFile);
$this->var1 = $vardata->var1;
$this->var2 = $vardata->var2;
```

but there are over 50 variables. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply foreach over all attributes to copy them over:

```
$vardata = $ToolBox->fileUnSerialize($myFile);
foreach ($vardata as $_attribute => $_value) {
    $this->$_attribute = $_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for most of it, but the arrays are not getting set correctly.

Comment: It should work for arrays to. (Just tested). It iterates over attributes regardless of type. Please specify which arrays or structures it stumbles for you.